# conversion from double to float

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I'm writing a program which basically calls func1 and func2 and prints

I'm in func1 and I'm in func2 ,

then asks the user for a input value , and

calculate the square root of  that value. For some reason I'm getting

```
1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\lab7.c\lab7.c\lab7.c(23): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'type'
1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\lab7.c\lab7.c\lab7.c(23): error C2198: 'sqrt' : too few arguments for call
1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\lab7.c\lab7.c\lab7.c(23): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========


#include <stdio.h>

#include <math.h>

#define Pi 3.14159
float func3(float); // function's prototype
void func1(void);
void func2(void);


 main()
{
float r, s;

func1();
func2();

printf("Enter a number: ");
scanf ("%f", &r);
fflush(stdin);
s = func3(r); // function call
printf("\nThe square root is %.2f",s);
getchar();
}


void func1(void)
{
    printf("\n I'm in function 1");  

}


void func2(void)
{
    printf("\n I'm in function 2");  

}


float func3(float r) //function
{
float a;

  printf("\n I'm in function 3");

a=sqrt(double(r*r));
return a;
}
```

Comment: The float to double is a warning only.  It doesn't like your sqrt() call.  Try casting the r*r to double explicitly (a line before) with double d = static_cast<double>(r*r), and then calling a = sqrt(d).  That might narrow it down.  Also, sqrt() should handle the casting for you, but might result in a warning.

Answer (score 0):

`float` has an implicit conversion to `double` so you don't even need to convert it, you can change your `area` function to the following.

```
float area(float r) //function
{
    printf("\n I'm in function 3");    
    return PI * r * r;  // Area = PI * r^2
}
```

Also, your math was incorrect, see the above function for the area of a circle. You basically had

```
a = sqrt(r^2)
```

which is basically just

```
a = r
```

Comment: I would also point out that the error message OP is seeing is being caused by incorrect cast notation. `a=sqrt(double(r*r));` should be `a=sqrt((double)r*r);`

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline `double(r*r);` is a perfectly valid cast / conversion.